# Regular Expression : Use last matched optional capture group

Tags: regex, capture-group

I would like to accomplish the following using a regular expression:

INPUT

```
M1  hello world 1234_5678  ip som lorem  9321_1231  iste natus error sit voluptatem   4313_4351  ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt   4312_1234
M2 magnam aliquam 4351_3143  sed quia non numquam  3123_1432
```

OUTPUT

```
M1    hello world   1234    5678 
M1    ip som lorem   9321    1231
M1    iste natus error sit voluptatem   4313    4351 
M2    magnam aliquam     4351    3143 
M2    sed quia non numquam    3123    1432
```

The reg-ex match

```
(M[1|2])?\s+(\D+)(\d{4})_(\d{4})(\n)?
```

and sub

```
\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\n
```

gets me close ( see: https://regex101.com/r/tKgCBi/1/ )

```
M1  hello world     1234    5678
    ip som lorem    9321    1231
    iste natus error sit voluptatem     4313    4351
    ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt       4312    1234

M2  magnam aliquam  4351    3143
    sed quia non numquam    3123    1432
```

How can I use the last (optionally) matched group when this (optional) match isn't made?  I assume it is setting \1 = NULL when (M[1|2])? fails.

(I am using Python's "re" module)

Comment: What is the real problem here? Your `"get me close" and "How can I use the last (optionally) matched group when this (optional) match isn't made? I assume it is setting \1 = NULL when (M[1|2])? fails." are not helpful.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean.  What clarification can I offer?

Comment: I'm using python's "re" module.  (Probably should have mentioned that to being with.  I edited my post.)

Comment: I mean the `(M[1|2])?` is not the *last* group. What exactly is wrong with the results you get?

Comment: Apologies.  I'm a reg-ex newbie.

The problem is that each line needs to start M1 if it comes after an M1 and before an M2.  (And vice versa).

Comment: @vrbatim do you try to print the last matched M1 or M2 for each line?

Comment: The first group is optional, and when it is not matched, it will be empty or even null (in Python 3.4 and lower).

Comment: I think [`(M[12])?\s+((?:[a-z]+\s+)+)(\d{4})_(\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/tKgCBi/2) should work for you

Comment: @anubhava --- does not seem to be the case: https://regex101.com/r/tKgCBi/1/

Comment: @anubhava When I match with that expression and sub \1\t\2\t\3\t\4\n I still get my "gets me close" output and not my desired one.  Namely:  there are lines that do not start with M1 or M2.

Comment: @luc14n0 yes. This is exactly what I'd like to do.

Comment: It has to be handled through code. `\1` will be populated in first match only and needs to be re-used for subsequent matches where `\1` is null.

Comment: @anubhava ok. So short answer is: it's not possible through pure regex expressions.

Comment: You may do it like this - https://ideone.com/gmUYDS (maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a 2-regex approach: match lines that qualify for splitting and then pass these matches to a callback method to process them further:

```
import re

s = '''M1  hello world 1234_5678  ip som lorem  9321_1231  iste natus error sit voluptatem   4313_4351  ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt   4312_1234
M2 magnam aliquam 4351_3143  sed quia non numquam  3123_1432'''

def repl(m):
    return re.sub(r'\s+(\D+)(\d{4})_(\d{4})', '{}\t\\1\t\\2\t\\3\n'.format(m.group(1)), m.group(2))

whole_line_pattern = r'(?m)^(M[12])?((?:\s+\D+\d{4}_\d{4})+)$[\n\r]*'
res = re.sub(whole_line_pattern, repl, s)
print(res)
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/A2fGc2)

**Pattern 1**:

- `(?m)^` - match the start of a line
- `(M[12])?` - Group 1 matching `M1` or `M2`
- `((?:\s+\D+\d{4}_\d{4})+)` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\D+` - 1+ non-digit chars
  - `\d{4}_\d{4}` - 4 digits, `_`, 4 digits
- `$[\n\r]*` - end of a line with 0+ line break chars

Each match is processed with `repl` method. The regex replacement finds

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\D+)`  - Group 1: one or more non-digit chars
- `(\d{4})` - Group 2: four digit chars
- `_` - a `_` symbol
- `(\d{4})`  - Group 2: four digit chars

The match is replaced with `M1` or `M2` (`m.group(1)`), and the `\\1`, etc. are backreferences to the capturing groups inserting the non-digit chunk and 4-digit chunks enclosed with tab chars.